# Add layout after widgets in QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I have a Qt Designer interface where I put a lot of buttons, labels,... and now I want to add a GridLayout that englobes all the stuff. How is it possible to make the widgets belong to the GridLayout a posteriori ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually placing your widgets and then applying a GridLayout is the only way in the designer. So after you have all the widgets you want select them all, then right click, choose Layout, choose Layout in a Grid.